# Is there a way to display some DIV in all sub-pages?

Tags: html, css, indexing

Is there some css/js/jquery to use on DIV in main index.html if I want to display it in all subpages without editing their code? E.g. `<div id="chatbox">` placed in main index.html to show in `/products/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic idea. My way is as follows.

Divide body into two parts or as required. Let's assume two parts. Top one gonna be fixed in all pages. Bottom one gonna change. So when you want to move to another page, just render contents in the bottom container after emptying it. Don't touch top container.